Are we assuming a relation to be transitive untill proven otherwise?
I do not know if the title would be correct title for the question but I think I am asking a valid question.
While studying set theory and relations we were often asked about whether a relation $R$ is an equivalence relation or not. In order to show that $R$ is an equivalence relation on set $A$ we have to prove, for all $a,b,c \in A$ that $R$ is:

Reflexive which means $(a, a), (b,b), (c,c) \in R$
Symmetric which means if $(a, b) \in R$ then $(b, a) \in R$
Transitive which means if $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b, c) \in R$ then $(a, c) \in R$

What I have in my mind is: A relation is transitive if $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b, c) \notin R$. We do not need to check if $(a, c) \in R$ by the fact that $(b, c) \notin R$. Why this is so?
Does this mean that we are assuming a relation to be transitive unless for $(a,b) \in R$ there exist $(b, c) \in R$ and then $(a, c) \notin R$? If yes then why?

I'm not sure I get your question. The negation of transitive property is: there is $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,c)\in R$ such that $(a,c)\not\in R$. These two properties (transitivity and its negation) cannot be both true at the same time. So showing one will disprove the other.

@freakish My question is why the absence of $(b, c) \in R$ makes a relation transitive. For example on $A = {a, b, c, d}$ the relation $R = {(a, b), (c, d)}$ is transitive just because $(b, c) \notin R$

Since $(b, c) \notin R$ we need not to bother to check for $(a, c) \in R$ and the relation is transitive.

"Checking" transitivity of a relation $R$ boils down to checking for every pair $(a,b),(b,c)$ with $aRb$ and $bRc$ we also have $aRc$. We do not have to look at pairs $(a,b),(b,c)$ that miss this property (i.e. pairs $(a,b),(b,c)$ with $(a,b)\notin R$ or $(b,c)\notin R$). If for instance every such pair $(a,b),(b,c)$ does not have the property then we can conclude immediately that the relation is transitive.

If $(a,b)\in R$ but $(b,c)\not \in R$ you do not need to check if $(a,c)\in R$ but you need to check if $(b,a)$ and $(a,a)$ are.  And if $(b,b)$ and $(a,b)$ is.  And if $(a,c)$ and $(c,a)$ and $(a,a)$ is.  And if $(b,c)$ and $(c,a)$ and $(b,a)$ is.  And so on.  The definition isn't for just one set.  It is for all possible sets.

Consider a relation with $(a,b), (a,c), (c,b)$ in it and notthing else.  If we check $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ and see $(b,c)$ is missing we don't have to check for $(a,c)$.  But then we have to check for $(a,c)$ and $(c,b)$ making $(a,b)$ and we do have $(c,b)$ so we do have to check for $(a,b)$ and as it is there we are good. Then we have to check out $(c,b)$ and $(b,a)$ making $(c,a)$. As $(b,a)$ not there we don't have to check for $(c,a)$.

Okay.... to the point of your question.   If $(a,b), (a,c)$ are the only things in the relationship then it is transitive as you never have a $(w, y)$ and $(y,z)$. so there are not any $(w,y)$ and $(y,z)$ pairs to fail.  And if nothing fails everything passes.

If I we you if $a,b,c$ are actual elements of the set, I would NOT use $a,b,c$ as vairables. For reflexive we need $(w,w)$ for all (so we have to check $(a,a),(b,b),(c,c)$.  For symmetry we have to check if $(w,y)$ then $(y,w)$.  So the is more than just $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$.  This is $(a,c),(c,a)$ and checking $(b,c), (c,b)$.  And for transitive we need to check $(w,y),(y,z)$ implying $(w,z)$.  This implies a heck of a lot more to check than just $(a,b),(b,c)\implies (a,c)$.

While the title is inaccurate & wrong , the gist is indeed correct.
In general language , Implication $I \equiv [ P \implies Q ]$ is taken to mean that when $P$ is true , $Q$ must be true.
Due to the way Material Implication works in Mathematical logic , $I$ is additionally true when $P$ is false.
So , when we have Single relation like $(a,b)$ & there is no $x$ to give the relation like $(b,x)$ , then transitivity Property still holds.
Implication $I3 \equiv [ (a,b) \land (b,c) \implies (a,c) ]$ is vacuously true , because the $P$ Part is always false , no matter what the $Q$ Part is.
When we have at least 1 $x=c$ where the relation $(b,x)=(b,c)$ holds , then transitivity Property demands that $(a,c)$ must hold , else it is not transitive.
Examples :
$\{\}$ is transitive
$\{(a,b)\}$ is transitive
$\{(a,b),(a,c)\}$ is transitive , $(b,c)$ not necessary
$\{(a,b),(a,c),(a,d)\}$ is transitive , $(b,c)$ & $(c,d)$ not necessary
$\{(a,b),(a,c),(c,d)\}$ is not transitive : It is missing $(a,d)$
$\{(a,b),(a,c),(c,d),(a,d)\}$ is transitive , $(b,c)$ not necessary
ADDENDUM 1 :
We eliminate such weird cases by using Symmetry & reflexivity when "Defining" Equivalence.
The last Example needs $(b,a)$ , $(c,a)$ , $(d,c)$ , $(d,a)$ to be Symmetric.
Additionally , that Example needs $(a,a)$ , $(b,b)$ , $(c,c)$ , $(d,d)$ to be reflexive.
We then get Equivalence.
Pictorially , Black lines are last Example relations , while the Blue line make it Symmetric & the Purple lines make it reflexive. Over all , these we get Equivalence.

ADDENDUM 2 :
When checking for transitivity , we have to make sure that either (1) the "if" Part is false or (2) the "if" Part is true & the "then" Part is true , for every triplet $a,b,c$.
Even when triplets are like (1) , it is transitive.
Even when triplets are like (2) , it is transitive.
When some triplets are like (1) & the other triplets are like (2) , it is transitive.
It is not transitive when (& only when) we have a triplet $a,b,c$ where the "if" Part is true while the "then" Part is false.
Since the "if" Part is made of 2 relations : when one of those relations is false for some triplet , the "if" Part is false & the Implication is true & hence transitivity is not disproved by that triplet. We will still have to check all other triplets to conclude on transitivity.

I can't find an example proposed by Roger Godement so I'll give it from memory. He tells a woman that "when he's 500 years old, he'll make love to her 5 times a day" is TRUE.

In Mathematical logic , that will indeed be true , assuming Roger Godement never reaches 500 years , @StéphaneJaouen , though that is known as vacuously true.

The confusion here is about logical deductions. I define a property $P$ of any group of people as follows. If all boys in the group are American, then the group has the property $P$, and otherwise it does not.
Consider groups defined as follows
Group 1: A group of 10 American girls.
Group 2: A group of 10 American boys.
Group 3: A group of 5 Asian girls and 5 American boys.
Group 4: A group of 5 Asian boys and 5 American boys.
Group 5: A group of 5 Asian girls and 5 American girls.
Group 6: A group of 5 Asian boys and 5 American girls.
To check if a group has property $P$, you can simply ignore the girls of the group, as they do not affect the validity of the property. On the other hand, if you find any, even one, non-American boy, you do not need to check further - you can say that the group does not have property $P$.
For example, Group 2 and Group 3 have property $P$ but Group 4 and Group 6 don't. What about Group 1 and Group 5? Well, they also have the property $P$ since there is no boy at all. This is the main point. If Group 1/5 did not have property $P$, there must be a boy who is non-American. But there isn't. So, they must have the property $P$.
In exact analogy, call $(a,b,c)$ a boy if $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ are in $R$, and call $(a,b,c)$ American if $(a,c)$ is in $R$. If there is no boy, for example in the relation $\{(1,2),(3,4)\}$ on $\{1,2,3,4\}$, there is no "boy" who is non-American (since there are no boys at all), so the relation is transitive.
All logical implications work this way. If you have a property $P$ defined as "If object satisfies A, then object satisfies B", then a group which has no elements satisfying $A$, must have the property $P$, since you cannot find an evidence against property $P$ (an evidence is an object satisfying $A$ but not $B$).
So, this property is said to be vacuously true if there is no object satisfying $A$.
Hope this helps. Ask if you still have any trouble. :)
